# How to determine the voicemail phone number in Android

Tags: android, voicemail

How can I determine the phone's voicemail number in Android code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use getVoiceMailNumber() in the TelephonyManager class, please note that this may not work with all cell phone providers:

[Android TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

Answer (score 3):

Call [`getVoiceMailNumber()`](http://goo.gl/jjhhR) on the `TelephonyManager`.